# Changing background colour for a few seconds only with jQuery

Tags: jquery

When clicking on a certain element, I want another element's background to become, say, red for x seconds before coming back to its original colour, all of this without using UI jQuery, only jQuery. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var $el = $("#my-element"),
    x = 5000,
    originalColor = $el.css("background");

$el.css("background", "red");
setTimeout(function(){
  $el.css("background", originalColor);
}, x);
```

Comment: Works well thanks ! As a sidepoint is there any way to animate the colour change still without UI jQuery ?

Comment: @drake035, sure is, just include the colour plugin.https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#element1_ID").on('click', function() {  // click on first element
    var bg = $("element2_ID").css('background'); // store original background
    $("element2_ID").css('background', 'red'); //change second element background
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("element2_ID").css('background', bg); // change it back after ...
    }, 1000); // waiting one second
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4GKD8/)

```
$('.b').on('click', function() {

    var time = 2000;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.a').css("background-color", "green");
    }, time);
});​
```